# BeautifulSoup error regarding running any prograam

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I am running any program, I get the error as :

> C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No
>   parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available html
>   parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if
>   you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual
>   environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 17 of the file abc.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

```
BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml"))
```

to this:

```
BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

I am not getting any solution to solve this error.

Comment: Warning and errors are completely different things. Change your title to warning. A programs runs without error even if you see warnings.

Answer (score 0):

When you run you code, you probably have `BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP))` or `soup(text)`. Change that to `BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "lxml"))`or `soup(text,'lxml')` to stop the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the parser when using BeautifulSoup

**EX**:

```
BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, 'html.parser')
```

or

```
BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, 'lxml')
```